# Calling AngularJS Function in Angular 14 (TS)

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, function-call

I currently have a JS controller file containing the following eventbus and function

```
 if (window.parent.eventBus) {
        window.parent.eventBus.on("action", function() {
            JSFunction();
        });
    }

    function JSFunction() {
        **stuff**
    }
```

I want to call said JSFunction() in my Typescript component for Angular 14 via emit. I believe something like.

```
somefunc() {
    this.JSFunction.emit("action")
}
```

Any ideas on how I might proceed?

Comment: so you are trying to call `.emit()` on a function?

Comment: Yes, I need to do something like this.